# what's wrong with my clearInterval?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to `clearInterval` based on a condition. What's wrong with it?

```
function Dog() {
    var x = 0;
    var s = setInterval(function y() {
        console.log(x++);
        if (x == 0) clearInterval(s);
    }, 1000);
    return '';
};
Dog();
```

Comment: Please explain clearly what the actual problem is. *What's wrong with it?* - People will not find the problem and provide a solution.

Comment: `x` will never be `0` in the `f (x == 0)` statement so `clearInterval(s)` is never called.

Comment: It's an infinite loop

Answer (score 0):

console.log(x++); // X will set to 1 at first call

if (x == 0) clearInterval(s); // Never executed... Until overflow of the x

Answer (score 0):

`x` starts at `0`.

On line one of your function, you increment it. So it will be `1`.

On line two, you test if it is `0`. It isn't.

Then the interval runs. 2 isn't 0. 3 isn't 0. And so on.

The condition is never met.

Answer (score 0):

Your x won't be 0 ever...

```
function Dog() {
  var x = 0;
  var s = setInterval(function y() {
    console.log(x++);
    if (x == 1) clearInterval(s);
  }, 1000);
  return '';
};
Dog();
```

---

Just reminder:

x++: returns actual x and increment after

```
var x = 0;
console.log(x++); // returns 0
console.log(x); // returns 1
```

++x: increment and return x

```
var x = 0;
console.log(++x); // returns 1
console.log(x); // returns 1
```